# Veritasium - Firing bullet in block - along center and away from center

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

This question is about [this video on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vWVZ6APXM4w), in which a bullet is fired vertically into the center of a wooden block from below, sending the block up into the air. Next, a bullet is fired vertically but off-center into a similar block from below, again causing the block to rise into the air, but simultaneously to rotate. The video asks for a prediction as to which block will rise higher.

Please post your guess/prediction/solution along with answer or in comments.

My first guess was that air friction decreases when object is rotating, but now I think that's not the reason.

Someone please shed some light on this.

#### EDIT

Is it possible that the first bullet went deeper inside the first block and thus the first block had lesser kinetic energy than expected?

Comment: Wow, Derek Muller must be a magician! I thought the rotating one would go to a lesser height

Comment: I am sorry for not being active on my own question but I seriously have a little (if any) idea about what you are talking about. Its been really long since I studied physics. `:P` but I just love your enthusiasm. All of you are awesome. I really admire physics and Physicists

Answer (score 15):

The system needs to conserve momentum. In both cases, the momentum is whatever m*v is for the bullet. Since it's the same in both cases, the bullet and block have the same vertical velocity.

Mechanical energy is not conserved. The reason the block hit on the side has more kinetic energy is that the bullet converted less of its kinetic energy into heat upon impact. We would find that this bullet penetrated less far into the block.

Comment: I don't understand why linear momentum is conserved in second case. I mean, some of the energy is gone into rotating and system and this less energy for translation. I agree the being inelastic collision, energy is not conserved but what about what about that missing `0.5*I*w^2` energy that didn't go into transnational kinetic energy?

Comment: Momentum is conserved because that's completely general in mechanics. The rest of your comment does not make sense to me.

Comment: So if the block was pinned in it's center where would the bullet momentum go? Linear momentum would not be conserved even if the block was spinning as a result. So what makes this case different? I think Isaac's 2nd law applies, and not a blanket statement about linear momentum.

Comment: I challenge you to calculate the take off speed and the rotation with your assumption and show us mathematically why it is so.

Comment: If the block were pinned, the pin would exert a force on the block, so momentum wouldn't be conserved. Obviously, momentum isn't conserved when there's an outside force on the system. Momentum would go into the pin and whatever the pin is attached to.

Comment: The final momentum of the bullet is not the same for the two cases. So not the same quantity of momentum is transfered, resulting on different heights that are _too small to measure_ in the videos.

Comment: @MarkEichenlaub please show your calculations supporting your claim.

Comment: No. I do not need to show any calculations because the argument stands on its own. "You are wrong because you didn't write an equation" is not a valid criticism. I am under no such obligation when the answer stands on its own, which this one does. My claim is that momentum is conserved. What calculation do you want for that? Do you want a general proof of conservation of momentum? Go learn high school physics.

Comment: Laws of motion: $$ \begin{aligned} \vec{L} & = m \Delta \vec{v}_{cg} \\ \vec{H}_{cg} & = I_{cg} \Delta \vec{\omega} \end{aligned} $$ Sum of linear and angular momenta equals changes in linear and angular velocities with mass $m$ and mass moment of inertia at the cg $I_{cg}$. Take it from here... Do it for both the block and the bullet and show me the $v_{block}^{final}$ is always the same regardless of where $x$ the bullet hits.

Comment: @ja72 You're completely off base here.  If you accept Newton's Second Law for point particles, then it follows immediately that if the net external force on a system of particles is zero in a particular direction, then the momentum of the system in that direction is conserved.  There is really nothing else that you need mathematically here.

Comment: @joshphysics I think you mean third law.

Comment: @MarkEichenlaub Well, I suppose I actually mean both; use 2nd to give $\sum \mathbf F_i = \sum \dot{\mathbf p_i}$ then write $\sum \mathbf F_i = \sum \mathbf F_i^\mathrm{ext} + \sum \mathbf F_i^\mathrm{int}$ and use third law to show $\sum \mathbf F_i^\mathrm{int}=0$, and the result follows.  Am I missing something?

Comment: yeah, that's right. it just seems like the third law is doing the heavy lifting there. I agree with that derivation.

Comment: Here is my confusion I think. I track the center of the block which initially is the CG, but after the bullet strikes the CG moves to the right. So the momentum of the bullet is conserved and transferred to the new CG which makes the block take off. I was looking at the velocity at the center of the block, which is **less** the further the bullet strikes. My equations are correct, just my measurement is wrong. I need to update my posting.

Comment: BTW, my background is in Rigid Body dynamics so it is natural for me to figure out what each body is doing separately, although here it may be better to just combine the bullet and block after the impact.

Comment: Yeah, okay. That's actually exactly what I was saying in this comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74707/veritasium-firing-bullet-in-block-along-center-and-away-from-center/74718?noredirect=1#comment154919_74729

Comment: I have added a new answer http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/75531/392 which describes mathematically what is going on here, and supports what @MarkEichenlaub has said in his answer.

Comment: This answers/comments are horrible! This experiment is the well-Known ballistic pendulum, just "vertical" to avoid someone looks up it in his elementary physics textbook.

Comment: @Georg No, this answer is completely correct. Your negativity is not helping anything, and you have completely failed to point out anything wrong with what I said.

Comment: The system also needs to conserve angular momentum, so you can also get the final angular momentum about the center of mass.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the mathematical treatment of this experiment. A block of mass $m_{block}$ is at rest when struck by a bullet of mass $m_{bullet}$ traveling with $v_{bullet}$ at a distance $x$ from the center of the block.

If the impact is perfectly plastic then the linear velocity of the block at the impact point should equal the velocity of the bullet after the impact. If the momentum transferred from the bullet to the block is $J$ then the change in speed for the bullet during the impact is

$$ \Delta v_{bullet} = - \frac{J}{m_{bullet}} $$

The same momentum $J$ affects the block by imparting linear and angular velocity at the center of gravity of

$$ \begin{aligned} \Delta v_{block} & = \frac{J}{m_{block}}
\\ \Delta \omega_{block} & = \frac{x\, J}{I_{block}} \end{aligned} $$

where $I_{block}$ is the mass moment of inertia of the block.

For a purely plastic contact setting the final relative speed equal to zero means

$$ \begin{aligned} 
 \Delta v_{block} + x \, \Delta \omega_{block} & = v_{bullet} + \Delta v_{bullet} \\
  \frac{J}{m_{block}} + \frac{x^2\, J}{I_{block}} & = v_{bullet} - \frac{J}{m_{bullet}} 
\end{aligned} $$

which is solved for:
 $$   J  = \frac{v_{bullet}}{ \frac{1}{m_{bullet}} + \frac{1}{m_{block}} + \frac{x^2}{I_{block}} } $$

Now for the trick. The combined center of gravity is at $x_{cg} = x \frac{  m_{bullet}} { m_{block} +m_{bullet} } $ so the take off speed of the new cg is

$$ \begin{aligned} 
   v_{cg} & = \Delta v_{block} + x_{cg} \Delta \omega_{block} \\
          & =  \frac{J}{m_{block}} + x \left( \frac{  m_{bullet}} { m_{block} +m_{bullet} } \right) \frac{x\, J}{I_{block}} \\
   v_{cg} & =\left( \frac{  m_{bullet}} { m_{block} +m_{bullet} } \right) v_{bullet}
\end{aligned} $$

The above expression means that the take of speed (and hence the height) of the cg of the combined block and bullet *does not* depend on the impact location $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I think I got it.

You cannot apply *mechanical* energy conservation to an inelastic collision, which is happening when the bullet is getting stuck into the block.

So in the first case the bullet is losing more *mechanical* energy by being fired into the center of the block than the second case, so when they reach the same height the block in the second case has more *mechanical* energy(because it must have lost lesser energy).

The fact that they will go to the same height is fairly simple to prove, by momentum conservation which can be applied for any kind of collision, elastic or inelastic.

The bullet has the same momentum initially in both cases, and the mass of the final system(Block + bullet) is same in both the cases so we get the same initial *linear* velocity for both cases, which implies they will both go to the same height.

Comment: But how are you sure that bullet went deeper in first case? And case II also has some angular momentum. Can you prove this by conservation of angular momentum?

Comment: You will only get the angular velocity by conserving angular momentum. And thats exactly what I'm saying, the bullet must have gone deeper in the first case than second leading to more energy loss in the first. Note that this does not mean it will apply lesser *impulse* in the second case. The equation of momentum is same in both cases.

Answer (score -1):

I was thinking the same thing you were: spinning reduced the air resistance. Since the spinning trick helps bullets travel faster with barrels that have riffling.

A lot of people are considering that it is probably that the block hit dead center because by hitting the block dead-center the collision was supposedly more inelastic.

Although I am going to be honest here and claim that there argument makes sense, I have a suggestion for testing both explanations:

1) Conduct a similar experiment but instead of using a wooden block use a material that will have a more elastic collision. If the results are slightly different it probably was due to heat loss. If not air-resistance was the cause.

2) Conduct a similar experiment with a wooden block but in a vacuum, [I don't know where one can find a vacuum as large other than space, but no matter]. If they travel the same distance then it was due to energy loss in heat, otherwise air-resistance.

Comment: I don't think we can perform your two experiments because I really don't have a gun :P. And Dr. Derek will tell the solution to this on Tuesday. I will post the link to that video under the question.

Answer (score -4):

The answer is: less

Some amount of the momentum (energy) transferred results in 
spin of the block, so less momentum (energy) is left for the 
rise. 
WRT thw idea that off-center hit will transfer more/less 
momentum: nonsense!
The time needed to stop the bullet in the block is much 
shorter than any movement of the block. 
That is why that arrangement is called "ballistic". 
The original version is a wooden Block (or a chest filled with 
cotton or wet clay) hinged as a pendulum bob. 
This is the traditional equipment used to measure momentum 
of rifle bullets depicted in every basic mechanics textbook.

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/balpen.html

https://www.google.de/search?q=ballistic+pendulum&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=CxAeUtirOoeZhQfn94DADw&sqi=2&ved=0CDQQsAQ&biw=1338&bih=911

Comment: I'm interested to hear how you think linear momentum is converted into angular momentum...

Comment: @Michael Take a "beam" (eg a ruler) and rest it at its ends on two chairs maybe. Then hit it from below with a thin stick, this will represent the bullet. First in the middle, then close to one end. Nothing superseeds experiment.

Comment: This is nonsense. Linear momentum cannot be transferred into angular momentum about the center of mass. Linear momentum is exactly equal to mass times velocity of center of mass.

Comment: The links you posted do not support your answer. You are simply unambiguously wrong. The linear momentum is exactly the same in both cases, not less in one of them. This is not an arguable point - it is completely clear to anyone with the most basic knowledge of introductory physics.

Comment: @Georg Please please try to understand that angular momentum does not mean "rotation about the centre." *Compute* the angular momentum in both cases before and after. Linear and angular momentum are **seperately** conserved in this problem. You *never* convert one into the other. They are seperate conservations laws. They even have different dimensions!

Comment: I understand you confusion, but this is a case where your intuition has apparently been incorrectly formed. The only cure for that is training. In this case just draw a black box around the system, don't think about what is happening on the inside, and apply the global conservation laws. You don't even need to know about the block! You could also think of the (not too hard) ways that your argument could be used to build a perpetual motion device (hint: physics is time reversible).

Comment: @Michael Brown What ever your 2angular momentum might be, the rotation about the centre exists and needs to be "fuelled". Re reversibility of physics: the impact of the bullet is a very irreversible action, called "inelastic".

Comment: @Georg What I'm saying is that the angular momentum is the same before and after the impact. It is not "fuelled" by a transfer of linear momentum. It was there to begin with.

Comment: @Mark Eichenlaub If linear momentum were identical, the impact would have been less irreversible in case of off-center impact. (to get some extra energy for rotation) The basic priciple of ballistic measurement is that the impact is much faster than the pendulum swing, and all details of the impact do not matter.

Comment: What part of mass*velocity don't you understand? That's the formula for momentum, and by hypothesis it's the same in both cases. End of story.