Why do we only see the distance traveled inside the block by the bullet in this problem?
In one of a very old veritasium video he discusses a problem of firing a bullet on a block. Here is the simpler version of it: Suppose we have a cuboid shaped block on a frictionless table, and we shoot a bullet with speed $V$ directly at the center of it. The bullet gets embedded in the block, and suppose the system (bullet+ deformed block) ends up with some velocity $v$. It must be that $V>v$, otherwise it would mean the system gained energy from the collision which is not possible.
Now consider a second case where we shoot the same bullet close to one o edges of the cube. Here, the translational kinetic energy of the system would be same as in the first case (because by conservation of linear momentum $v$ is the same here as well), but it has also gained some rotational kinetic energy. So, now it has more energy compared to the system in the first case. This means there is less energy loss in the second case; the deformation must be less as well. The video concludes that the bullet must have traveled a smaller distance into the cube in the second case.
Now I have two questions regarding this:

Is there any way just using forces (i.e Newton's laws and not including the discussion of energy) to rigorously prove that the bullet must have traveled a smaller distance into the cube?

Even if the bullet is embedded a smaller distance into the cube, how does this prove that energy loss is less in the second case? Because, if we mean that friction between block and bullet must have done less work on the bullet in the second case because travels less distance inside the block, it doesn't seem truly correct. The problem is that we should look at the whole displacement of bullet (i.e displacement with respect to ground) to calculate the work done as the block is also moving. So, why does only the distance the bullet has traveled inside the block matter?



Related post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74707/179151

I said related, not duplicate. It's about the same video

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


The problem is that we should look at the whole displacement of the bullet
(i.e. displacement with respect to ground) to calculate the work done
as the block is also moving. So, why does only the distance the bullet
has travelled inside the block matter?

My take on this is that the lost energy is the result of friction as the bullet travels through the wood, and friction is proportional to the distance the bullet travels through the wood, as that is where the actual surface-to-surface interaction occurs.
Imagine having a very long plank of wood in the train and rubbing some sandpaper on it as you run to the back of the train. Even if you run so fast that the sandpaper looks like it was stationary to someone standing beside the track, that would not stop the sandpaper from creating friction and heat because that is caused by the motion relative to the wood and does not care about the external motion. If you now run back to the front of the train with the sandpaper pressed on the wood at the same speed relative to the plank of wood, you do not generate more heat simply because you have travelled a greater distance relative to someone looking from the trackside. The motion of the train makes no difference to how much heat is generated by the sandpaper, and we know from special relativity we have no way of knowing if the train is 'really' stationary or moving. The same goes for the bullet moving relative to the block of wood. The motion of the wood relative to some chosen background reference frame makes no difference to the heat generated by the motion of the bullet relative to the wood.

But is there a way just using forces and Newton's law to prove it so
it's easy to imagine rather than using the argument of energy
conservation – Virender Bhardwaj

The problem with using "just force" is that the bullet does not stop instantly relative to the wood, and the $\text{force} \times \text{distance} = \text{energy}$, so we are back to working with energy again. The conservation of energy can only be used to calculate how much energy was lost as heat once the velocity after the collision has been determined, and we need to use the conservation of linear and angular momentum to do that. Once the velocity has been determined, then the kinetic energy can be calculated, and what is missing from the total initial energy is assumed to have been lost in the form of heat and possibly sound. The heat generated is a function of friction and plastic deformation as the bullet travels through the wood.

we write the NET force on the particle, and we see its displacement
w.r.t ground. We get work done by all the forces this way – Virender Bhardwaj

Consider an aircraft with an airspeed of $40 \ \text{kph}$ flying against a headwind of $40 \ \text{kph}$. Its ground speed is zero. The NET horizontal force acting on the aircraft is zero. The thrust of the aircraft is balanced by the drag of air friction and it maintains constant airspeed. In this case, a ground observer cannot calculate the force acting on the aircraft by considering its displacement relative to the ground.
Consider the following problem: A block of wood is being pulled with constant velocity relative to a carpeted surface, and we are given the following parameters:

The coefficient of friction ($\mu$) of wood on carpet is $1.0$.
The block moves with a velocity of $5 \ \text{m/s}$ wrt the carpet.
The block moves a distance of $20 \ \text{m}$ wrt the carpet.
The heat generated in the block-carpet system is proportional to
$980 \ \text{J}$.
The mass of the block is $98 \ \text{kg}$.

What is the force indicated by a spring balance dragging the block, and how much energy is produced as heat?
Solution: The proper force indicated on the spring balance is equal to the friction force, so $F_f = \mu m g = 1 \times 10 \times 9.8 = 98 \ \text{N}$. The heat generated (W) is given by $W= fd = 98\times 20 = 1960\ $ joules.
If the carpet is the floor of a train and the train is moving at $105 \ \text{m/s}$ in the opposite direction to which the block is being dragged in, what is the force acting on the block according to a trackside observer on the ground? Since the block was moving at $5 \ \text{m/s}$ over a distance of $20 \ \text{m}$, the time for the experiment was $t = d/v =20/5 = 4 \ \text{s}$. The distance ($x$) travelled by the block in the ground frame is $x = vt = (105-5) \times 4 = 400 \ \text{m}$. By the work-energy relationship, the force acting on the block is equal to $F = W/d = 1960/400 = 4.9 \ \text{N}$. This result is not the proper force indicated on the spring balance. It is not even what we would normally call the friction force acting on the block. If we work out the coefficient of friction based on this force calculated in the ground frame, it will not be the same as the standard figure given in a list of friction coefficients in an engineering reference. This is because doing the measurement based on displacement measured in a reference frame where both the block and the carpet are moving is not the standard way to do the calculation.
Consider stretching a spring. The manufacturer of the spring states the stiffness constant ($k$) of the spring is $100 \ \text{N/m}$. This information can be used to calibrate a spring balance made from this spring.
If the end of the spring is displaced by $0.2 \ \text{m}$ and using the equation for Hooke's law $F = kx$, the proper force acting on the spring is $F = 100\times 0.2 = 20 \ \text{N}$. The potential energy stored in the spring is $W = fd = 20 \times 0.2 = 4 \ \text{J}$. If the person stretching the spring is on a train moving at $100 \ \text{m/s}$ and the spring is stretched over a period of $2 \ \text{s}$, the end of the spring will have been displaced by a distance of $100 \times 2 + 0.2 = 200.2 \ \text{m}$ according to an observer on the ground. By the ground observer's calculations, the force acting on the spring $ F = kx =100 \times 200.2 \ \text{N}$ and using the work-energy relationship, the ground observer calculates the energy stored in the spring as $ W = fd = 200.2 \times 200.2 = 40,080 \ \text{J}$. This is an incorrect result because the spring constant assumes the displacement is the rest frame of the spring. Even worse, the calculations in the ground frame where the spring is moving are time-dependent. If the spring is stretched over a period of $4 \ \text{s}$, the trains will have moved a distance of $400 \ \text{m}$ during the experiment, and the displacement of the spring will be $400.2 \ \text{m}$ this time. The ground observer now calculates the energy stored in the spring as $ W = fd = 400.2 \times 400.2 = 160,160 \ \text{J}$. The energy stored in the rest frame of the spring is not time-dependent. Using the work-energy relationship $F = W/d$, the ground observer will get different results for the applied force, depending on how long it takes to stretch the spring. We could, of course, get correct and consistent results in the ground frame by allowing for time, etc., but the calculations would basically be converting the situation back to the rest frame. The calculation in the ground frame is more complicated, and the results for force in the ground frame are confusing and non-intuitive and do not agree with the proper force indicated by a spring balance.
In the Veritasium experiment, less energy is lost as heat when the bullet strikes off-centre. It is a fact that the bullet will penetrate less deeply into the wood block because the friction is proportional to the distance the bullet travels relative to the block.
The claim that force is always calculated relative to a ground frame amounts to claiming a preferred reference frame and contradicts special relativity. In the example of the train, claiming the only valid horizontal displacement is one measured relative to the ground is nonsense because the Earth is moving.
In the video, Veritasium asks how the experiment can be improved to exaggerate the difference between the penetration of the bullet in the dead centre and off-centre cases. The answer can be found in this spreadsheet calculator here. The parameters in the blue cells can be changed. Everything else is calculated. The yellow cell is the energy lost as heat, and this is proportional to the penetration depth in the block. In the spreadsheet, the dimensions of the block and bullet can be altered as can the masses and the velocity of the bullet. The offset ($X_b$) of the bullet from the centre can also be entered. The spreadsheet calculates precise moments of inertia for the combined bullet and block system using the parallel axis theorem, etc.

I also thought of this example once but actually the work done is relative right. If we are calculating all other energies like linear kinetic energy if system or rotational Kinetic energy. Then we should also see the work done by friction w.r.t ground??

@VirenderBhardwaj I have extended my answer in response to your comment.

When we measure the work done on an object, we are normally moving an object against an opposing force. This means we should do the measurement of distance relative to whatever is providing the opposing force. Forces do work independent of the presence of other forces, and you can figure out the work done by a force from any reference frame.

@KDP No, if we are calculating the work done w.r.t to ground then we always have to see the displacement w.r.t ground. In you example of train and spring block system. The static friction is also acting w.r.t ground and that will do some work w.r.t ground as well. Therefore if are calculating total work done on block then it has to be work done by both of them. Remember how we derive the work energy theorem for a particle. We derive it from Newton's equation and in that we write the NET force on the particle and we see it's displacement w.r.t ground. We get work done by all the forces this way

@BioPhysicist I have taken your comments on board and rewritten the last part of my answer.  I have also added a spreadsheet that calculates what actually happens. While I agree that work can be calculated in any reference frame,  I am surprised that you are tacitly agreeing (by your silence on the matter) with the OP on his opinion that displacement should only be measured in the ground frame which amounts to asserting a preferred reference frame in relativity.

@KDP Silence doesn't really mean anything here; comments on your answer are not the place for me to have a discussion with the OP.

@KDP In your train and wooden block example you said "assume a block moves 20m for 5 sec. W.r.t train and coefficient of friction is 1. These are wrong assumptions because if only 1 force would be acting on the block which is friction. Then u can't presume the TIME as well as the distance. Because that will depend on newton law. If we assume that it moved for 5 seconds and then stops after 20m distance WITH RESPECT TO TRAIN t then first of all we can't do the calculations w.r.t train because the friction would be acting on the train as well and so the frame will become non inertial

@KDP there are other mistakes in other calculations as well. You have assumed a lot of things out of air. But still if you are saying that the energy loss depends on the distance traveled by the bullet w.r.t block then w.r.t what point on the block exactly are you talking about? Because each point on the block will have different displacement. So the displacement of bullet w.r.t each point will be different .Its just very hard to even calculate and process

@KDP and even if we assume that the mass of the train is a lot and the friction compared to that is negligible so we don't need to apply pseudo force them also you can't assume all the things like the force, time as well displacement because the third will depend on the first two. And whole calculation would be different.for. e.g Assuming the block moves 20m with initial speed 5m/sec. The acceleration of block comes out to be -25/40m/sec^2 which will change the calculations

@KDP in my first comment I by mistake write the time instead of the speed. So, don't bother about that

"But still if you are saying that the energy loss depends on the distance traveled by the bullet w.r.t block then w.r.t what point on the block exactly are you talking about? Because each point on the block will have different displacement. "- Virender Bhardwaj. Just imagine you are an ant on the block and from that point of view the block is stationary. You appear to want to make things much more complicated for yourself by insisting that all measurements should be done wrt the ground frame.

As a result of the many comments associated with your post, you summarized in your comment to me that your issue with the analysis is as follows:

If we are saying the bullet when fired off center travels less
distance inside the block due to the work done by the stopping
frictional force being less on the bullet, I don’t think that’s true.
That’s because to calculate work done w.r.t ground you have to look at
the displacement of bullet w.r.t ground because the block is also
moving.  We can't just equate it to distance traveled inside the
block.

It is not necessary to calculate the work based on the displacement w.r.t. ground rather than w.r.t the center of mass of the block-bullet system.
Although kinetic energy is reference frame dependent, the change in kinetic energy is the same for different inertial frames of reference. And since the net work done on an object (in this case, the work done by the block on the bullet making the relative velocity between them zero) equals the change in kinetic energy of the object, the net work done by the block on the bullet is also independent of the inertial frame of reference.
In this example, since the mass of the bullet is probably about 100 times less than the mass of the wood block, the center of mass is roughly that of the block, which can then be considered an inertial frame of reference as the ground.
That said, I would like to make further comments on the video.
The video initially concludes that since less energy is dissipated in the block in the case of the off centered bullet, that means the penetration of the bullet must have been less. But subsequently here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLYoyLcdGPc they find that based on an xray the bullet penetration looked the same.
From this they finally realized that the theoretical difference in penetration would be immeasurable since 97% of the initial KE of the bullet was dissipated during penetration (I confirmed this with my own calculations). A similar observation was made in a separate article here: https://www.compadre.org/ivv/docs/Bullet-Block_Assignment.pdf
I would also add that any difference in height would likely also be immeasurable, even if all other conditions were equal (e.g., uniformity of the wood at the two entry sites).
All of this doesn't negate the fact that the additional rotational kinetic energy must be the result of less energy being dissipated in the block when the bullet enters off center.
Hope this helps.

But even if  we calculate the displacement of bullet w.r.t COM from the time it just collides to the block till the time it gains the same speed. It's not necessarily equal to the distance traveled INSIDE the block because it will be equal to "displacement vector of COM w.r.t ground - displacement vector of bullet w.r.t to ground " how does it necessarily equal to the distance traveled inside the block??

@VirenderBhardwaj The only “distance” that matters is the depth of penetration of the bullet. And that’s the same in any non relativistic reference frame
